# Difference between Visual Studio 2005 professional edition and visual studio 2005 express edition

Tags: visual-studio-2005

What are the differences between Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition and Visual Studio 2005 Express Edition? Which is the best for Windows 7? Can we compile applications built in Professional Edition on Express Edition?

Answer (score 2):

The Express editions are fully featured apart from the fact that you can't run plugins with them. So that means no ReSharper and the like.

The project files aren't changed in any way so you can open projects created in the Professional edition in the Express edition and vice versa.

However, if you are thinking of using the Express edition it would be worth upgrading to the 2010 version as that supports .NET 4, Silverlight 4, WPF etc.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the Express editions also do not support source control.

Comment: Also, the last time I checked(its been a while) the express versions would only allow you to have a single project in a solution.